# Force an Async task to stop from main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an app which requests data from server on regular basis (fixed time interval , 20sec) using JSON.

My current implementation includes having a loop inside an async task , with a 20 sec "sleep" condition. This however doesn't seem like a good implmentation. my question is is there a better implmentation. also is there a good way to force stop an async task from its main thread.?

Another option is to change the code , and let the client send one request and for the server to have the server loop the answers back.Which is a better implmentation thank you in advance :)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String RegistrartionID = RegisID();

            while (true){
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Start_Term", args[0]));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Dest_Term", args[1]));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RegistrartionID",
                        RegistrartionID));
                Log.i("Start_Term", args[0]);
                Log.i("Dest_Term", args[1]);
                Log.i("RegistrartionID", RegistrartionID);
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        URL_SEND_CHOSEN_TERMINALS, "POST", params);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: you can't stop a while (true) loop without a break from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it's not a good implementation. Contrary to popular beliefs, `AsyncTask` is not intended for long/undetermined-in-time processes, it's meant for short tasks so it can exit afterwards and end.

For your purpose, I'd recommend using a `Service`. Basically because you've the advantage you start it and stop it within the Activity you define it. You may see its documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Also [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) may help, it's a very good example.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , ur method worked with alarm manager suggestion from user3229580 , thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a Service who executes your AsyncTask and for loop it every 20seconds, you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)